# Error in dyn.load(dll_copy_file) when building Rcpp package on Mac

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I'm building my own Rcpp Package (name: RUtilities) on Mac. However, I encountered the following error when executing `devtools::document()`

```
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
─  DONE (RUtilities)
Error in dyn.load(dll_copy_file) : 
  unable to load shared object '/var/folders/70/0x058vd10ts57r4ck5j2j3s00000gn/T//RtmpIXnrlU/pkgload13d793cdb33ea/RUtilities.so':
  dlopen(/var/folders/70/0x058vd10ts57r4ck5j2j3s00000gn/T//RtmpIXnrlU/pkgload13d793cdb33ea/RUtilities.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '__RUtilities_test'
```

My current attempts:

1. delete the .so, .o files in the `src` folder and rerun the code.
2. delete the RUtilities.so file in the `/var/folders/70/` folder.

However, the error persists.

This problem is very strange to me, because the same package can be installed correctly on my Linux server.

I suspect there is something wrong with the R version, since my Linux server uses R3.6, while my mac uses R4.1. Should I modify the `Makevars` file when the R version changes? My `Makevars` file looks like this right now:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include/


CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_LIBS += $(shell ${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "RcppParallel::RcppParallelLibs()")
```

Also, my Mac uses the Apple M1 chip. Is this chip the problem?

Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: If it works on one machine of yours, but not the other, it is likely related to your setup on the failing machine.  R 3.6.* versus 4.1.* should not matter to Rcpp.  If you can point to a repository or make the example _minimally complete and verifiable_ we may be able to help, otherwise it is tough.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! I rebuilt the package file by file. I finally found the problem was one row in the `/inst/include/RUtilities.h file`: `RcppExport SEXP C_spdinv_arma ( SEXP X_ )`. After deleting it, the package was installed successfully. Is this a bug in `devtool` in R 4.1?

Comment: We cannot tell, your example is not public or reproducible. _Somehow_ you ended up with a line in your file causing an error. At this point only you can know or tell how it got here.  It seems very unlikely to be cause by Rcpp.